# Since there are some different headers of arches that NDK gave, which directory should I use

Tags: android, android-ndk, header

In the path $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-[n]/, there are some sub-directories, such arch-arm, arch-arm64, arch-mips, can I simply use the header files of arch-arm/usr/include/? 
If the answer is yes, and then, does the compiler replace these headers for each platforms at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that would be wrong. And the differences are not only between architectures, bit also between toolchains and between platform levels. **`ndk-build`** will point each compiler to appropriate include directories.

But why do you ask? What problem did you face?

Comment: ”**ndk-build** will point each compiler to appropriate include directories“，does this mean that I can simple include the header in the folder arch-arm?     I asked because I have to set the "include path" in eclipse to avoid some error msg, such as "Unresolved inclusion: <android/log.h>" .

Comment: the answer that google given all is to use the path `$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-[n]/arch-arm/include/`

Comment: If you are looking for a way to satisfy Eclipse CDT parsers, then yes, you can point to arch-arm.